# Index geological time in xts

Tags: r, class, time, xts

I would like to work with a time series of geological dates (represented as integers in million of years before present) in `xts`.

Is there a time class that I can use to index these data?
If not, what's the work-around?
Most of the classes I can find work with calendar dates/years...

**What would be the best fit for a datatype/class for this case?**